# how to compare two python installation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two (stand-alone) installations of python-2.7.5 with numpy 1.7.0 and scipy 0.13.1.

Unfortunately, for some operations (with matrix) I got different results depending on the installation used.

I think I have some libraries that have different version.

How could I compare the versions of all the common libraries of my installations.

Thanks for any help.

In fact, any idea of the reason of the differences between my installations are welcome.

Comment: May I ask why you desire to have two different installations of the same python version on the same machine?  (Maybe you have a great reason! If so I'll be educated.)

Comment: Something like `import numpy; numpy.__version__`?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: One is mine and the other is from my client. I need to tell him why we don't have the same results.

Comment: @Reti43: I know the version of scipy and numpy. I want to compare all version of all libraries...

Comment: `pip freeze` from the command line? [Documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)

Comment: @stephan Unfortunately, we don't use pip... (we do archaic work ;-)

Comment: Could you try to narrow down which operations in particular give different results? You might get slightly different results for linear algebra operations if your two versions are linked against different BLAS and/or LAPACK libraries.

Comment: Also take a look at `numpy.show_config()` for information about the underlying LAPACK and BLAS libraries used by numpy.

Comment: @ali_m & Waren: Thanks for these information. I see differences between atlas. I will have a look. LAPACK, BLAS , ATLAS seems to be a part of the key...